# Can you improve and lower your active heartrate during exercise

Tags: weightlifting, cardio, heart-rate

Are you able to improve your heartrate at an active state? I know athletes have a lower resting heart rate, but I am interested in my heart rate not spiking so high when I weightlift. I noticed my heartrate gets very high (165 to 170) doing bulgarian split squats 4 sets of 10. While this is just one exercise, it really wears me out to have a heartrate that high, I feel very exhausted afterwards. But what can I do to lower this heartrate, or in general doing weightlifting? Some ideas:

more anabolic workouts such as box jumps, or HIIT?
more aerobic cardio?
anaerobic alactic such as sprints?

OR something else entirely... any ideas?

Comment: Do you do any cardio? Or workout days to improve work capacity?

Comment: Sometimes a cardio day once a week. Not a lot at the moment. It's an assumption of mine that cardio would benefit myself but I can't find anything online that states it'll actually prevent my heart rate from going as high

Comment: I do a reverse linear block periodization, 4 day push pull workout with half and half heavy/light days. I am somewhat limited to workout as much as I want to. I seem to do fine other than quad workouts involving compound movements

Comment: HR is a response to the muscles needing more oxygen. However, if you don't warm up and you shoot your heartrate high from a dead stop (no pun intended) then it can tire you out. What do you do for warmups?

Comment: Maybe see [this article](https://www.menshealth.com/fitness/a19547944/high-intensity-continuous-training/)